# Spring Websocket heap space Error with concurrent Request

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, websocket, tomcat8, spring-websocket

I am using Spring WebSocket. I am seeing a gradual increase in heap memory whenever I am creating WebSocket session. From the heap dump i found that the below objects is acquiring most of the heap memory : 
 `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer` and `java.nio.HeapCharBuffer`
 and there are multiple instances of these objects. i am using `WebSocketConfigurer` for WebSocket configuration.